# Is Excel coauthoring possible with Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We want to manipulate cells (+ read cell data) of an Excel workbook stored on Sharepoint. A C# service will be used for this automation. A human user plus the automation are supposed to look at the same workbook without harming each other.

Is the Graph api suitable for this at all?

I only had a brief look at Graph and followed a simple tutorial. I would now have to write a test app to see if our requirements are met, but I was hoping someone here has done something similar.

Currently, we are using Excel interop (yes, it is a bad idea to use it in a service) and we know no other automated approach to coauthoring.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, coauthoring works with Microsoft Graph. We replaced our previous interop solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: So why are you ask? Just for leaving logs for the future?

Comment: When I asked, I did not know the answer. I posted the answer because I thought this is helpful for others facing the same use case.